# Binding double value to textbox

Tags: c#

I have an `ObservableCollection` filling a Datagrid `DGCommands`, and some textboxes' `Text` attribute defined like the following :

```
Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Costs,
Mode=TwoWay,
ElementName=DGCommands,
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Alright, now when i parse a double value from one of the textboxes, for example :

```
bool costs_valid = double.TryParse(txtboxCosts.Text, out _costs) // 1,8 i get 18;
```

I tried to solve the issue with this method but i'm not sure if it's the best possible solution :

```
public static double DoubleParseCostum(string val)
{
        double res = 0;
        bool res_valid = double.TryParse(val, out res);
        if (val.ToString().Contains(_DECIMAL_)) return res;
        else
        {
            if ("." != _DECIMAL_ && val.Contains(".")) return double.Parse(val.Replace(".", _DECIMAL_));
            if ("," != _DECIMAL_ && val.Contains(",")) return double.Parse(val.Replace(",", _DECIMAL_));
        }
        return res;
}
```

Where

```
_DECIMAL_ = Convert.ToChar(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator).ToString();
```

**EDIT :**

Changed the title from "*Parsing string to double gives Int*" To the current one because the real problem was in the binding and not the parsing, cuz when i want to change 1.8 to 1,8 i get 18  as result on lost focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a long-shot... I'm wondering whether the underlying problem that you're actually trying to solve (without realising it) is that all WPF applications default to using the "en-US" locale. You can solve this on startup of the application by doing:

```
FrameworkElement
   .LanguageProperty
   .OverrideMetadata(
    typeof(FrameworkElement),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

Comment: Perfect Thank you :D

Answer (score 2):

Try this : `double.Parse("1.8", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: i want to leave the Decimal character open to any Culture

Comment: @Mugiwara Good luck with that, but you're missing the point (chuckle). Different cultures use different characters to mean different things. For example Sometimes '.' represents the thousand separatos, sometimes it represents the decimal point. Perhaps CultureInfo.CurrentCulture would do?

Answer (score 2):

In this example I picked a culture (Austria) that uses the comma as a decimal separator to show how to do it. You can set the culture to anything you want, of course, including the current UI culture.

```
var testCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-AT");
var text = "1,8";
double result;
var ok = double.TryParse(text, NumberStyles.Float, testCulture, out result);
Console.WriteLine("And the result is: {0:000.0000}", result);
```

Output:

```
And the result is: 001.8000
```

[Code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NV2ou3)

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution, just like @Richardissimo said, WPF uses the 'en-US' culture by default and comma (,) is then treated as a thousand separator and not as a decimal sign. so i set the ConverterCulture property to use the system's default culture :

```
<TextBox Name="txtboxCosts" Style="{StaticResource txtboxDefault2}"
xmlns:gl="clr-namespace:System.Globalization;assembly=mscorlib"                       
Text="{Binding SelectedItem.proCosts, 
       Mode=TwoWay,   
       ElementName=DGCommands,
       StringFormat={}{0:N2},
       UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
       ConverterCulture={x:Static gl:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}}"/>
```

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? Your approach requires you to put that ConverterCulture in **every** Binding. My suggestion only requires you to add one line in one place to make your entire application work properly, with no other changes required, and it will work for whatever culture the user of your application is using.

Comment: Not really ^^" i didn't get it until now, it's perfect thank you so much, and thank you for pointing out again even though i said i found a solution, you saved me a lot of time, I really appreciate it :D